# I want to put random bytes inside bytes.fromhex()

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
bytes.fromhex("AA BB CC "+random.randbytes(2)+"FF")
```

expected result: AA BB CC 42 F1 FF

How do I code it to write it like my intent?

Comment: `bytes.fromhex("AA BB CC") + random.randbytes(2) + bytes.fromhex("FF")` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks to reply. Your method throws an error.

Comment: sorry. I made a mistake. Your method is run normally.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
import random
import string
bytes.fromhex("AA BB CC " + ''.join(random.choices(string.hexdigits, k=4)) + " FF")
```